# Is there a way to have a private and a public github repository and have a secret folder in the private one

Tags: git, github

How do you have two github repositories, one private and one public, and I have a secret file in the private one. I would like to allow people to contribute to the public one but not see the .py file in the private folder and instead see a .py file with a different contents, how can I do this without having to manually sync them? The Github docs repo has a bot but I want to know if there is a simpler way.

My secret folder has a .py file in it, I could just replace it with another .py file but I want this to happen automatically.

Comment: Git has no concept of public or private repositories.

Comment: I meant github @Acorn

Comment: What do you want to store in the private directory?

Comment: A .py file with secret variables

Comment: I edited the question to clarify this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to have two copies of the same repository like this, but in practice it's very hard to do because the histories will need to be independent, meaning things like merges and conflict resolution will quickly become difficult.

Since your problem is a file with secrets, the best practice is to create a template file that contains everything that's reusable and public (that is, everything but the secrets) and then use a script to generate the actual Python file you want to use from the template and the secrets.  Both the file with the secrets and the generated file should be ignored.  You can run this script as part of your normal deployment or project bootstrap process if you like.

The reason this is a good idea is because storing secrets in your repository is unwise.  It often happens for various reasons that source code leaks.  This can happen in many ways, including accidentally serving your `.git` directory over HTTP.  If your repository doesn't contain anything private (other than your source code), then the risk of compromise is much lower.

If you're deploying a production service, then it's best to store secrets in some specialized secret store, such as Vault or your CI system's store (e.g., GitHub Actions's secret store) and pass them in via the environment.

Answer (score 1):

Maintain the private-use `.py` module in a submodule, whose path your public project inserts ahead of its own in the module search path. People cloning just the public repository will have an empty private directory (since they can't clone the private repository it stays empty, like an unmounted mount point) and python's module search will find the public version.